# Finding the equation of displacement

Tags: integration

How to find equation of displacement when you know the equation of velocity. And the finding the constant when you know that at t=0 displacement is 2?

Comment: What is the relation between displacement and velocity?

Comment: I know that velocity is derivative of displacement. So to find displacement you should find antiderivative of velocity. So should i integrate function of velocity and then solve for c?

Comment: You got it ! Just go on.

Comment: The thing is i did everything till the part where i have to solve for c. I have sin(1/2) on one of the sides and probably this is the  part of algebra that i missed :D Can i just devide both sides by sin(1/2)?

Comment: What is $\sin(1/2)$ and where is this coming from ?

Comment: I had cos in my velocity function. After differentiating the function i have left with ( -5sin(2-3t) / 3 ) +c . I have to find the constant now, when t=0 displacement=2m

Comment: Since nobody knows what you have been given, how do you want an answer ? To find $c$ plug the conditions and solve for $c$.

Comment: Variable t is in the sin brackets when i put the conditions into the function i got the answer above. all i need is to solve for c now and i dont know if i can devide both sides by sin to solve for c.

Comment: v=5/4 cos(3/4t - 1/2)dt

Answer (score 1):

If you have the velocity in terms of time
$$
v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt} 
$$
you can integrate 
$$
x(t) - x(0) = \int\limits_0^t v(\tau) d\tau
$$